# Setting up FTP for specific folders

Tags: ftp

I want users to be able to upload files via FTP to my site (IIS 7.5). Once the file is uploaded, then I want to process the file. Is there some guide that steps through how to setup FTP to point to a specific location where I want the files to be dropped?  Can I setup FTP to point to a different subfolder based on the user that logs in?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking to set up FTP user isolation. Here's a guide:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/305/configuring-ftp-user-isolation-in-iis-7